# Linux sort -u does not work

Tags: sorting

I tried to sort a big file with more than 10000 data. I want to find the unique species (like Fe, La, etc.) in the file (17x200.o_neighbors.raw.dat) Ideally, I should get the result like below (see the 4th column)

> FRAME     0  9194 Fe  6330SI
>   FRAME    11  9194 La 12858H    6330SI

However, I got results like this

> FRAME     0  9194 Fe  6330SI
>   FRAME    11  9194 La 12858H    6330SI
>   FRAME    19  9194 La 13537H    6330SI

There are two "La" species. How can I get the duplicated one removed.

Here is my command

```
grep FRAME 17x200.o_neighbors.raw.dat | grep 9194 |sort -k 2 -n |sort -k 4 -u
```

the first `sort -k 2 -n` is to get timeseries order
the second `sort -k 4 -u` is to get unique species data

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use an actual RDBMS?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually, I did it, however, I failed.

Comment: Reply Red Cricket : I use these BASH scripts in PERL scripts. I did not think about it. Any further suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '($4 in a==0) { # if $4 not hashed yet, ...
    a[$4]=$0          # hash it to a
}
END {                 # after all record have been processed
    for(i in a)       # iterate all hashed records
        print a[i]    # output
} ' file
FRAME 0 9194 Fe 6330SI
FRAME 11 9194 La 12858H 6330SI
```

Now you can `sort` that output.

Answer (score 1):

Per the `sort` manpage, the `-k` flag works like so:

> -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
>         start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of line)

So `-k 4` defines a key from position `4` to the end of the line; so in your example, its values are { `Fe 6330SI`, `La 12858H 6330SI`, `La 13537H 6330SI` }, which are all distinct.

To fix this, you need to define a key *from* position `4` *to* position `4`:

```
... | sort -k 4,4 -u
```

Answer (score 0):

I test it. I use command below to filter the duplicated one. But I do not understand why.

```
grep FRAME 17x200.o_neighbors.raw.dat | grep 9194 |sort -k 2 -n |sort -k 3,4 -u
```

Any explanation would be appreciated.